# AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer appears to be escaping parent bounds

Tags: ios, view, storyboard, constraints, addsubview

I'm having an issue fitting a AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer inside its parents bounds.

Here is the contextual code:

```
    capturePreview = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    guard let capturePreview = capturePreview else { return }
```

When I have

```
   capturePreview.frame = cameraView.bounds
   cameraView.layer.addSublayer(capturePreview)
```

The following occurs:

[image]

And when I have

```
capturePreview.bounds = cameraView.layer.bounds
cameraView.layer.addSublayer(capturePreview)
```

this happens
[image]

I'm trying to get the preview layer to fit inside the black box in the next picture

[image]

From what I have seen in the documentation, I'm not sure where I am going wrong. Thanks for any help. For reference I will add the constraints I gave in storyboard.

[image]

Comment: set Frame of preview layer in viewdidlayout subview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using something like:

```
capturePreview.frame = cameraView.bounds
cameraView.layer.addSublayer(capturePreview)
cameraView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing. Thank you. Do you know why in particular this caused the issue?

Comment: As far as I can tell, in iOS, UIViews do not clip child views by default. The preview layer probably has a certain fixed aspect ratio, so when your cameraView's frame has a different aspect ratio, the preview layer will go out of the bound of cameraView, but it is still visible, so setting clipsToBounds just cuts the parts that is outside the cameraView, which is probably what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added constraints attaching `capturePreview` to `cameraView`? You will need to do this in code. Add constraints so that `capturePreview`'s left, right, top and bottom edges are attached to `cameraView`'s corresponding edges.

**Objective C**

```
NSLayoutConstraint *topConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:capturePreview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:cameraView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
NSLayoutConstraint *leftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:capturePreview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:cameraView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
NSLayoutConstraint *rightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:capturePreview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:cameraView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
NSLayoutConstraint *bottomConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:capturePreview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:cameraView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];

[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[topConstraint, bottomConstraint, leftConstraint, rightConstraint]];
```

**Swift**

```
let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: capturePreview, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cameraView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: capturePreview, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cameraView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
let leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: capturePreview, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cameraView, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
let rightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: capturePreview, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cameraView, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([topConstraint, bottomConstraint, leftConstraint, rightConstraint])
```